# How to dynamically handle UNIX/Windows directory separators in yaml files

Tags: php, configuration, path, yaml

We facing a problem where we need to configure a path in one of our `config-file.yml`. It's a path to an CLI-Script. We facing an old known problem "directory separators" for UNIX/Windows - `/` - `\`  . Now we want to configure just one path for both OSs.

Currently we need to switch the path manually depending on the currently used OS. This breaks our VCS handling / application stability all the time.

#### Unix

```
bin_path: path/to/script
```

#### Windows

```
bin_path: path\to\script
```

Is there something like a placeholder known from [PHP superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`? We focusing a solution where we not need to replace the separators in our scripts. I stuck in this problem for a couple of times when using yaml files.

Comment: Isn't unix notation handled properly on Windows?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php reads: _On windows realpath() will change unix style paths to windows style._

Comment: @AlexBlex yes, but not in this case. The command is fired by http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html which breaks on windows by using unix separators.

Comment: And what stops you to `realpath` filenames before passing them to the component?

Comment: Nothing right now. But is there a solution with not touching the path on script side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML is a data description language and as such has no support for data flowing into the YAML document from the outside (i.e. variables you can use in the document). The only thing you can theoretically do is to structure your YAML document in a way that lets you select the value you actually want afterwards. Example:

```
bin_path:
  unix: path/to/script
  windows: path\to\script
```

Then, when loading the file, you can select the appropriate path for the current operating system. However, this seems convoluted compared to the approach where you simply replace `/` with `\` when on Windows.

---

An other solution is to just use one path configured for Windows or UNIX like in the following example. In this way you don't need to configure a specific path for each operation system.

```
bin_path: path/to/script
```

In e.g. PHP you could normalize your pass inside your application by using [realpath](http://php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php).

```
realpath('path/to/script'); //creates an absolute path including OS based directory separators
```

Comment: Please also add a solution of using a script to replace the directory separators or using `realpath` in a PHP case. I'll go to mark this answer as right so. Damn this text based configuration files without having access to programming logics. Somethink like a yaml parser which delivers the ability to insert script logics inside a configuration file would be nice. I probably going to write one and share it on GitHub.

Comment: In a case of using programming languages, which are undepending on the OS (PHP, node.js, Java, etc.) its a must to have the ablility of configurate your system without using software switches inside application logic.

Comment: I will not give you a PHP solution because a) you didn't give your existing PHP code and b) I don't really know much PHP. However, you may be interested in things like preprocessing YAML files with some templating language, like for example Ansible or Saltstack do it with Jinja. That way, you can first insert variables into the YAML file by executing the template, and then read the resulting YAML.